# Black Screen after booting from USB to Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

This is my first try on the Ubuntu.
The original laptop ( Asus A43S Intel i5, 4 GB RAM,Nvidia GT-520M ) is running:

Windows 10 (free upgrade from window 7 during the window 10 introduction period)

Created the bootable USB using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.8.7, with the BIOS ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64 
Booted into BIOS using F2 button, selected to boot from USB (UEFI enabled)
Popped up the selection page, Try Ubuntu without installing, install Ubuntu etc.
Tried both option but the results are the same.Right after selection the screen goes black (but the background was lit and the fan started running a little faster. This remains the same for over an hour without any progress. Is my machine too old to run Ubuntu? Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Things you might want to confirm:

- Your machine has the same architecture you are installing. i.e., it's a 64 bit since you indicated you are installing  ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd**64**
- Try different bios settings such as [Raid on](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006748/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html)
- Create a bootable USB using [rufus](https://rufus.ie/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go to bios and select boot from usb:

It can also be done by "boot selection menu" by using "ESC" key
 :or google the boot keys for your device:

Once you enter boot menu: "select the uefi driver in which you installed ubuntu.."

If it dosent work try to install ubntu on a Dvd using PowerIso software

and after installing it on DvD try to boot it from "boot selection menu"

Answer (score 0):

**No machine is too old to run Linux**

First thing that I would suggest you is to go to the boot menu option rather than getting into BIOS every time. (For me the key is F11 and I'm using Lenovo Ideapad 330)

Secondly boot the system in Windows and download Rufus (best according to me) and use it to burn the OS on the USB drive. Also check the SHA256 of the OS that you downloaded with the source, if it matches then you're good to go.